# Mix the result of union all query and order them by row by row

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I apologize if the title of the question is unclear.

I have this sample query:

```
SELECT a.i_id,
       a.i_item,
       a.i_count
  FROM abc a
 WHERE i_id = 123
UNION ALL
SELECT b.j_id,
       b.j_item,
       b.j_count
  FROM def b
 WHERE j_id = 4567
```

which returns the result in the screenshot 1.
[image]

I want to modify the query so it can return what is shown in the screenshot 2.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

DERIVED TABLE SORTING

```
select * from 
(    SELECT a.i_id,
           a.i_item,
           a.i_count
      FROM abc a
     WHERE i_id = 123
    UNION ALL
    SELECT b.j_id,
           b.j_item,
           b.j_count
      FROM def b
     WHERE j_id = 4567
) X
order by i_item
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, in your real example, you can't just `ORDER BY i_item` or `ORDER BY i_count` to get your desired order then:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/05d22/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE abc ( i_id, i_item, i_count ) AS
SELECT 123, 'apple',  100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, 'banana', 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, 'candy',  300 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE def ( j_id, j_item, j_count ) AS
SELECT 4567, 'apple',  100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4567, 'banana', 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4567, 'candy',  300 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT i_id,
       i_item,
       i_count
FROM   (
  SELECT i_id,
         i_item,
         i_count,
         ROWNUM,
         1
    FROM abc
   WHERE i_id = 123
  UNION ALL
  SELECT j_id,
         j_item,
         j_count,
         ROWNUM,
         2
    FROM def
   WHERE j_id = 4567
  ORDER BY 4, 5
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/05d22/4/0)**:

```
| I_ID | I_ITEM | I_COUNT |
|------|--------|---------|
|  123 |  apple |     100 |
| 4567 |  apple |     100 |
|  123 | banana |     200 |
| 4567 | banana |     200 |
|  123 |  candy |     300 |
| 4567 |  candy |     300 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a view and Use the following simple query, alternatively:

```
CREATE VIEW ghi AS
SELECT a.i_id,
       a.i_item,
       a.i_count
  FROM abc a
 WHERE i_id = 123
UNION ALL
SELECT b.j_id,
       b.j_item,
       b.j_count
  FROM def b
 WHERE j_id = 4567;  

SELECT *
  FROM ghi
 ORDER BY  i_item, i_id;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c9e0f/1)

Answer (score 0):

Without an `ORDER BY` clause, the order of a query result is completely left to chance. If the orange part of the result stems from the first query and the blue one from the second, this is in no way guaranteed.

So add an `ORDER BY` clause at the end of your query. It is not clear by what attribute you want to sort. Here are some possibilities:

Option 1: Keep same items together, always first one id then the other.

```
...
ORDER BY i_item, i_id;
```

Option 2: Keep same counts together, always first one ID then the other

```
...
ORDER BY i_count, i_id;
```

Option 3: Alternate between IDs, start with first items, then second ones, ...

```
ORDER BY row_number() over (partition by i_id order by i_item), i_id;
```